# Drop Down menu breaks in Firefox - table-cell at fault?

Tags: html, css, firefox, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown with a skew thats working pretty much how I want it too, however in Firefox the drop down portion appears way below the main nav. I can fix it by removing "display:table-cell" but then it breaks other properties and makes the nav not scale properly. (designing for a responsive site) Any suggestions for a firefox fix?

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
          http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>test doc1</title>

    <!-- hack for bug in Web Developer addon for Firefox.  Used for
     development and debugging only-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css" href="x" />

    <style type="text/css">

    .menu_nav
    {
        position:relative;
    }

     nav ul {
        display: table;
        height: 2em;
        list-style:none;
        width:95%;
        font-family:BentonSans, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size:81.3%;


       }

     nav ul li {
        color: white;
        font-weight:bold;
        display: table-cell;
        height: 2em;
        padding: 0 2em 0 2em;
        -moz-transform: skew(25deg);
        -o-transform: skew(25deg);   /* Opera fails */
        -webkit-transform: skew(25deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(25deg);
        transform: skew(25deg);
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align: center;
        border-left:.25px solid white;
        position:relative;
        background:#cc0000;

        }

      nav ul li a {
        color: inherit;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-25deg);  
        -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
        transform: skew(-25deg);
        padding:1em;
        }

       nav ul dl {
        display:none;
        -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
        -o-transform: skew(-25deg);  
        -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(-25deg);
        transform: skew(-25deg);
        float:left;
        background:none repeat scroll #fff;
      padding:0;
      margin:0
             }

nav ul li dl {position:absolute; left:-2em; background:none repeat scroll #fff; }

nav ul li dl a{display: block;}

       nav ul dl li {
        font-size:12px;
        float:left;
        color:#fff;
        -moz-transform: skew(0deg);
        -o-transform: skew(0deg);  
        -webkit-transform: skew(0deg);
        -ms-transform: skew(0deg);
        transform: skew(0deg);
        width:100%; 
        height:37px;
        background:#ddd;
        padding:0;
        margin-left:10px;
        padding-left:10px;
       }
         nav ul dl li a { 
         width:100%; 
         color: inherit;
         display: block;
         text-decoration: none;
         -moz-transform: skew(0deg);
         -o-transform: skew(0deg);  
         -webkit-transform: skew(0deg);
         -ms-transform: skew(0deg);
         transform: skew(0deg);
         color:#000;
         float:left;
         text-align:left;
         padding:10px 0;
        }

       nav ul li:hover > dl {
           display:block;
           background:#ccc;

       }
          nav ul li dl li a:hover {
           display:block;
           background:#ccc;

       }



    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Project</h1>
    <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>ABOUT</span></a>
        <dl>
            <li class="menu_nav"><a href="#">HISTORY</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MISSION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>COMMUNITY ENGAGEMENT</span></a>
        <dl>
            <li><a href="#">GOOD NEIGHBOR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESS TO SPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YOUTH EMPOWERMENT & LEADERSHIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEERISM</a></li>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>STRATETIC INVESTMENTS</span></a>
            <dl>
            <li><a href="#">GOOD NEIGHBOR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESS TO SPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YOUTH EMPOWERMENT & LEADERSHIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEERISM</a></li>
        </dl>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>CHARITABLE GIVING</span></a>
            <dl>
            <li><a href="#">GOOD NEIGHBOR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESS TO SPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YOUTH EMPOWERMENT & LEADERSHIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEERISM</a></li>
        </dl>
     </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>NEWS</span></a>
            <dl>
            <li><a href="#">GOOD NEIGHBOR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESS TO SPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YOUTH EMPOWERMENT & LEADERSHIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEERISM</a></li>
        </dl>
     </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span>MULTIMEDIA</span></a>
            <dl>
            <li><a href="#">GOOD NEIGHBOR</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESS TO SPORTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">YOUTH EMPOWERMENT & LEADERSHIP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEERISM</a></li>
        </dl>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I remembered something about a browser not liking `position: absolute` inside `display: table-cell`. Quick google search brought me to this: http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/wNhD8/2/

I added `white-space: nowrap;` to `nav ul`

`display: inline-block;` to `nav ul li`

`margin-left:-5px;` to `nav ul li`

removed white border-left from `nav ul li`

Comment: Oh awesome - I'll give that a try thanks! Just real quick - do you see how the drop down sort of falls kinda overlapping behind part of the nav? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Yeah, should it be always behind the red background?

Comment: Maybe adding a little bit of margin top to DL ?

Comment: hm strange - your jfiddle demo looks fine but when I add it to my page it gets really wonky.. don't think there are any conflicts w my other code. Darn skewed menu...

Comment: I wouldn't skew.. I would use images, maybe SVGs.. Even retina displays render skew poorly :(